# Add table using append on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to add a table using jQuery's `appendTo` function whenever a certain button is clicked. Here's my code:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
   $("#divId").dialog("open");     
   $('#divId').appendTo('.table_width');
});
```

Note that in this code, `.table_width` is the table class and `#divId` is the div identity.  However, this does not seem to be working. Am I doing this the right way? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: append a class name? can you be clear on what you want to append

Answer (score 1):

Use `.append` instead of `.appendTo`. What I understand from your question is that you want to append an existing table to #divId.`.appendTo` will append your div to the table, which is not what you want.

Comment: no i just want to add show the table and add table row  to that table in the dialog box please if there is any code please help me its not working thanks in advance

Comment: I probably did not understand the question. Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a whole new table on every click, or just a table row?

Anyway, you need to use "add()" to create new elements. To add a new (empty) row to an existing table, use:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
   $('#existing_table').add('tr').addClass('.table_width');
});
```

This will append a new row with the "table_width" class. Not sure if that's what you want though ;)

Comment: there is add item button in the dialog box on that button  click i want row of the table to be added i have many codes in the net even clone in jquery

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
   $('#divId').append($('.table_width')).dialog("open");
});
```